# Removing words that are almost tags from titles

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, title

I've just been reviewing edits and I've noticed the same user removing words from titles that 'match' tags. e.g. this [Form resetting through Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313484/ax-2012-form-resetting-through-code) had it's title changed from:

**Ax 2012 Form resetting through Code**

To

**Form resetting through Code**

Although having the exact tag in the title is against the conventions here, the problem is that the particular technology the OP is asking about isn't mentioned anywhere else in the question, so anyone trying to understand the question has to check all of the tags to see which technology the question is about.

That seems like a bad edit to me as it makes it harder to understand the technology, and the word used in the title isn't actually the tag, so people searching for the same problem with that the spelling as per the title won't be able to find it.

Should these types of edits be rejected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having tags in your title, but make sure they blend nicely to the title:

> ### Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?

As opposed to

> ### PHP - Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions?

---

In your particular example, rephrasing the title while keeping the technology's name would probably be wiser.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the edit should be rejected *because the appropriate tag has not been added* (if it exists). The user may not have the privileges to create a tag or they may simply not have thought about it.

While we do want to remove **unnecessary** tags from titles we still want **complete** edits rather than half-done ones.